# "***" Does not contain a definition for "pnlMenu"

Tags: asp.net, database

Im trying to get info from my database into my html, and im almost there. but for some reason, when i tried something, it all went south, it doesnt want to grab anything, and i have no idea why. ill upload all of my code here. and yes, i know is messy.

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="home" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title> Micha de Haan's Portfolio </title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<!--    Alles tussen de header is de balk bovenin -->

<header>
<div class="ijzerenman"><a href="http://www.deijzerenman.nl/" ><img src="http://www.deijzerenman.nl/logo/logo.png" Width:="60px" height="60px"></a>    </div>
 <div class="verzekering"><a href="http://www.veenstradejong.nl/"target="_blank"><img src="styles/Logo.png" Width:="60px" height="60px"></a></div>

 <h1>
 <strong>Welkom op mijn portfolio</strong>
</h1>
 <ul>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

<%--     <div class="current1"><li><a href =" home.aspx.?    pageId=start">Home</a></li></div>
 <div class="orange"><li><a href="home.aspx.?pageId=overmij">Over mij</a></li></div>
 <div class="red"><li><a href="home.aspx.?pageId=logboek">Logboek</a></li></div>
 <div class="green"><li><a href="home.aspx.?pageId=ervaring">Ervaring</a></li></div>
 <div class="blue"><li><a href="home.aspx.?pageId=familie">Familie</a></li></div>
1-tabel aanmaken 'menu' met kolommen id, titel, pageid, kleur
2- daarna vullen met bovenstaande paginas
3 - alle records ophalen en doorlopen
4 -tijdens doorlopen stroing itemsoptellen
string strMenu += String.Format( @"<div class=\"{0}\"><li><a href=\"home.aspx.?pageId={1}\">{2}</a></li></div>", strKleur, strPageId, strTitle);
5- strMenu in literalcontrol
6 - toevoegen aan panel


--%>

 </ul>

<%

    string pageId = Request.QueryString["pageId"];
    if (pageId == null || pageId == "") pageId = "start";

     %>

   </header>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

ASPX.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageId = Request.QueryString["pageid"];
    //Vraagt de QueryString aan die in de url wordt aangegeven
    if (pageId == null) pageId = "start";
    // als de pageid Querystring niets is, dan is de pageId "start"
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCon"].ConnectionString;
    //zet de connectiestring "dbCon", zodat de gebruiker bij aanpasbare informatie kan
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    //maakt een nieuwe instantie aan van een SqlConnection. dit is een representatie van een open verbinding aan SQL Databases.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Menu", con);
    //een command die wordt gestuurd naar de database, die vraagt om * te selecten van Menu, waar de * con is, en Menu de Menu database.

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //Representeert een set van commands en een database connectie die worden gebruikt om een DataSet ( Een "cache" van data in het geheugen ) en om een SQL Database te updaten.
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    //  een "cache" van data in het geheugen
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    //refresht en updated de rijen in een database
    DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
    // pakt de tabels in de dataset, en loopt constant tot er geen tables meer te krijgen zijn.

    String content = "";
    //zet string content naar niets
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)// Voor elke rij in table.rows (alle rijen in de table) pakt hij de kleur, pageId en Titel, en zet ze inplaats van de nummers.
    {
        content += string.Format(@"<div class=""{0}""><li><a href=""home.aspx.?pageId={1}"">{2}</a></li></div>", row["Kleur"], row["PageId"], row["Titel"]);

    }
    this.pnlMenu.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(content));//zet de resultaten van de content string in het html bestand, waar de pnlMenu wordt gerefrenced.
}
}
```

Comment: Well, for a starter, I can't see a closing body or HTML tag... Your HTML seems a bit of a mess.

Comment: Also, you've got a massive chunk commented out in the middle of the HTML.

Comment: There is a body and html closing tag, its just that i cut out the part that seemed required. ill edit that. also, that part thats commented is supposed to be that way. its the part ofthe code im trying to replace with a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `namespace` in code behind, in this snippet the `myProject` namespace. It should look like this

```
using System;

namespace myProject
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

That should also be present in the aspx file header `Inherits` property

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="myProject.WebForm1" %>
```

You probably deleted some stuff by accident. It would be easiest to create a new page and copy-paste all the code.

Comment: Yeah, i put everything in a new file and it seems to work fine, thanks!